# Why incompatible return-types with wildcards compile in generic and non-generic methods override?

Tags: java, generics, overriding

What is the reason of such strange behavour? `List<? super Number>` is "narrower" ("more specialized") than `List<?>`, so code in example 1 below shall fail!  When I have `List<?>` return type in overridden method in Base class (interface), it is always OK to have `List<? super Number>` as return type of overriding method in Derived class (interface) - it compiles fine in examples like 1-3 and I understand why.

**1. Superinterface (I1) method is generic, subinterface (I2) method is not generic. Covariant return in subinterface (I2) compiles fine:**

```
interface I1 {
    public <T> List<? super Number> f() throws IOException;
}

interface I2 extends I1 {
    public List<?> f() throws EOFException; // compiles! covariant return is OK! 
}
```

**2. Both interface methods are generic - compile error in I2**. Superinterface (I1) method is generic, subinterface (I2) method is also generic. Covariant return in subinterface (I2) gives compile error *"return type is incompatible with I1.f()"*:

```
interface I1 {
    public <T> List<? super Number> f() throws IOException;
}

interface I2 extends I1 {
    public <T> List<?> f() throws EOFException; // covariant return fails 
}
```

**3. Both interface methods are non-generic - compile error in I2**. Superinterface (I1) method is non-generic, subinterface (I2) method is also non-generic. Covariant return in subinterface (I2) gives same compile error as in 2 - *"return type is incompatible with I1.f()"*:

```
interface I1 { 
    public List<? super Number> f() throws IOException;
} 

interface I2 extends I1 { 
    public List<?> f() throws EOFException; // covariant return fails 
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. I am curious to see valid explanation. The weird thing is that it even compiles this: `public List<String> f();`

Comment: I have racked my head over this question for a pretty long time myself. I have noticed a pattern where the code compiles only if the parent method declares a type parameter but the child doesn't (`<T>` in your case).

Comment: What happens if you call `i2.f()`? And if you call `i2.<String>f()`? I guess since there's no valid way to call the parametrised method without specifying the `T` class the compiler will always be able to distinguish the two methods... what if you change the original method to `public <T> List<? super Number> f(T t) throws IOException`? Does it give compilation error? I expect it to as now you could invoke this method with `i2.f(String s)` and type inference and the compiler won't know which one it is.